# How to push in heroku?

Tags: heroku, github, push

I clone my repo down and change something and commit,

but when I want to push like the tutorial:

```
git push heroku master
```

it tell me wrong:

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm sure I have log in,

so how can I push my repo correctly and deploy it?

Comment: add result of `git remote -v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Git Reference (http://gitref.org/remotes/#remote):

"So that you don't have to use the full URL of a remote repository every time you want to  synchronize with it, Git stores an alias or nickname for each remote repository URL you are interested in. You use the git remote command to manage this list of remote repos that you care about."

You can check if remote named "heroku" exists for your git repo using:

```
git remote -v
```

If it doesn't exist, you need to add it before you can push updates as follows:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:appname.git
```

where appname should be the name of your app.